# Least value but not NULL in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to use function LEAST  in my procedure to find the smallest value. The problem is that some of the values might have been NULLs so if I do

```
select least(NULL,0,1) from dual
```

The answer I get is NULL, which is probably correct by is not something I am expecting to return. I would like to get the least real non zero value. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt that's actually your query. Maybe you're doing something more like this?

```
select least(some_column) from dual
```

If so, change it to this:

```
select least(some_column) from dual where some_column is not null
```

---

Or, if you're doing something more like this, where you can't just use `where` to filter the set,

```
select least(expr1,expr2,expr3) from dual
```

do this:

```
select least(coalesce(expr1, 12345), coalesce(expr2, 12345), coalesce(expr3, 12345)) from dual
```

Where `12345` is a value big enough that it would only be chosen if all other expressions are `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks @tenfour, I had to compare multiple results some of which would have been NULLs. coalesce solved my problem.

Comment: LEAST should always be called with at least 2 parameters, otherwise it's useless; your initial examples are potentially confusing to newbies. Also, returning `12345` (or whatever arbitraily large number you use) instead of NULL if all arguments are NULL is a bug waiting to happen, IMHO.

Comment: I agree; actually I feel if you want this kind of control over the set, you should really rotate it maybe using subquery factoring, then the logic becomes much more sane.

Answer (score 21):

If any argument is NULL, you want to take the least of the other argument(s). If all arguments are NULL, you want to return NULL.

I might use something like this for two arguments:

```
LEAST(NVL(colA,colB), NVL(colB,colA))
```

It starts getting ugly for >2 arguments though:

```
LEAST(COALESCE(colA,colB,colC)
     ,COALESCE(colB,colA,colC)
     ,COALESCE(colC,colA,colB))
```

At which point I'd start considering magic values; but this can be buggy (e.g. what if one of the values legitimately *is* the magic value?):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN r = maxv THEN NULL ELSE r END AS result
FROM   (SELECT LEAST(NVL(:colA,maxv)
                    ,NVL(:colB,maxv)
                    ,NVL(:colC,maxv)) AS r, maxv
        FROM   (SELECT 9.999999999999999999999999999999999999999e125
                       AS maxv FROM DUAL));
```

Comment: For two arguments there's a simpler formula: `coalesce(least(x, y), x, y)` this is simpler in the sense that there are only 2 function invocations. For 3 or more arguments, I believe your solution to be the most compact.

Answer (score 2):

Lowest value from column 1 to N:

```
SELECT
    LEAST(COALESCE(Col1, BINARY_DOUBLE_INFINITY),
          COALESCE(Col2, BINARY_DOUBLE_INFINITY),
          ... ,
          COALESCE(ColN, BINARY_DOUBLE_INFINITY)
    )
FROM MY_TABLE
```

Greatest value from column 1 to N:

```
SELECT
    GREATEST(
        COALESCE(Col1, -BINARY_DOUBLE_INFINITY),
        COALESCE(Col2, -BINARY_DOUBLE_INFINITY),
        ..., 
        COALESCE(ColN, -BINARY_DOUBLE_INFINITY)
    )
FROM MY_TABLE
```

To remove the infinity results from the query, just add the where clause checking if all the values are null. You can do that using the coalesce function as well:

```
WHERE COALESCE(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the three expressions in three orders in three 'coalesce' calls and putting these in the 'least' call will result the least of three, ignoring null unless all three expressions are null.

```
select least(coalesce(expr1, expr2, expr3), coalesce(expr2, expr3, expr1), coalesce(expr3, expr1, expr2)) from dual
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but the accepted answer looks better to me

Answer (score 0):

One way is to define own version of `LEAST/GREATEST` func:

```
-- here version for two params
WITH  FUNCTION least_improved(p1 IN NUMBER, p2 IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
    IF p1 IS NULL THEN
       RETURN p2;
    ELSIF p2 IS NULL THEN
       RETURN p1;
    ELSE
       RETURN LEAST(p1, p2);
    END IF; 
END;
SELECT least_improved(col1, col2)
FROM table_name;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of columns from which you want the min & max, you can UNPIVOT them into a single column, which then makes it simple; exclude NULLS from your single column & use a MIN() or MAX() to get what you want.

I needed to do this with about 50 date columns (not a great db design) and UNPIVOT seemed to be the most sensible / practical way of doing it

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT least(1, 2, 3, nvl(NULL,4)) FROM dual
```

Return: 1

```
SELECT GREATEST(1, 2, 3, nvl(NULL,0)) FROM dual
```

Return: 3