# Oracle SQL - Select oldest of 3 dates, but ignore NULLs

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have this Oracle SQL statement to get the oldest of 3 dates:

```
SELECT LEAST(DATE_1,DATE_2,DATE_3) FROM MYTABLE
```

However, if one of the dates is NULL, the entire LEAST function will return NULL, regardless of whether the the other dates are not NULL. I would like to get the oldest of the three dates, but ignore any NULL dates, so that the only time LEAST would return NULL is if all three dates are NULL.

I also cannot have the function return incorrect dates, so this will **not** work:

```
SELECT LEAST(NVL(DATE_1,SYSDATE),NVL(DATE_2,SYSDATE),NVL(DATE_3,SYSDATE)) FROM MYTABLE
```

What's the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with what you did?  The only issue I see is that if all three values are null it will return sysdate- for that you can write a case statement to get out of it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313770/least-value-but-not-null-in-oracle-sql)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
SELECT LEAST(COALESCE(DATE_1, DATE_2, DATE_3),
             COALESCE(DATE_2, DATE_1, DATE_3),
             COALESCE(DATE_3, DATE_2, DATE_1)
            )
FROM MYTABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

`SELECT LEAST(NVL(DATE_1,TO_DATE('9999-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')), NVL(DATE_2,TO_DATE('9999-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')), NVL(DATE_3,TO_DATE('9999-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd'))) FROM MYTABLE`

The only downside is that it returns 9999-01-01 instead of NULL if all three are NULL.

Comment: This works when you add a CASE/WHEN statement to check for 9999-01-01 and set it to NULL. But Gordon Linoff's answer was a little shorter lol

Comment: Yes, I would chose his too. :)

Comment: And I would not use `TO_DATE` to give date literals. Instead of `TO_DATE('9999-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')` why would you not want to use `DATE '9999-01-01'`?