# Combine multiple date columns into one date column

Tags: netezza

I want to combine multiple date columns by taking the ***least date value*** among date columns excluding the nulls values. I have tried various ways such as using 'case when' and 'Min' function but can't weed out NULL values. I am not looking for first non-NULL value either. What makes matters worst is that the 'LEAST' function is not available in Netezza.

My dummy data(not highlighted columns), my desired output(highlighted columns) is shown in the table below:

[image]

Comment: was - rating necessary or just convenient?

Comment: @stidgeon the referenced post doesn't reflect my question nor is it for Netezza database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Least value but not NULL in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313770/least-value-but-not-null-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: Thanks Sam. Unfortunately, Netezza doesn't have Least function. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the MIN and MAX functions in a netezza system work as simple scalar functions (as well as columnar functions) and you can give them multiple arguments. Essentially the same as LEAST. This example covers it for the MIN function but MAX is the same:

```
select min(a)
from (
    select  min(min(1,2),NULL) a
    union all 
    select 10
    union all
    select NULL
) x
```

Result is 10

To disregard possible NULL values with a NVL (same as DB2 coalesce function) and an "infinate" value of some sort. Replace line 3 in the above statement with this:

```
select  min(min(1,2),nvl(NULL,100)) a
```

Result is now 1

In you case you should be able to do this:

```
select patient_id,min(
    nvl(INDEX_DT,'9999-12-31'),
    nvl(PRE_FEVER_DT,'9999-12-31'),
    nvl(POST_FEVER_DT,'9999-12-31'),
    nvl(PRE_DIARR_DT,'9999-12-31'),
    nvl(PRE_DIARR_DT,'9999-12-31'),
    nvl(PRE_COUGH_DT,'9999-12-31'),
    nvl(POST_COUGH_DT,'9999-12-31')
) as signs_DT
```

Comment: Interesting Idea, I will test it tomorrow and update this thread. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

The `least()` function is available as a part of the SQL extension toolkit.

Here is the link to the least() function -> https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/netezza?topic=functions-least

Here is the install instructions -> https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/psfa/7.1.0?topic=setup-installing-netezza-sql-extensions-toolkit

SQL Toolkit can be downloaded from IBM Fix central.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, the VDI I'm working with doesn't allow the installation of extensions-super sad! :(