# How to use `GREATEST()` in Snowflake with null values?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to use `GREATEST()` in Snowflake, but whenever I have null values, I get `null` instead of the desired result:

```sql
select greatest(1,2,null);

-- null
```

This behavior has confused many, and it begins with the behavior of `GREATEST()` in Oracle, which Snowflake matches:

- [Handling Null in Greatest function in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186283/handling-null-in-greatest-function-in-oracle)

It has also being discussed in the Snowflake forums:

- https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009LHFw1SAH/greatest-and-null-values

Sample data:

```sql
create or replace table some_nulls
as (
    select $1 a, $2 b, $3 c
    from values(1.1, 2.3, null::float), (null, 2, 3.5), (1, null, 3), (null, null, null)
);

select greatest(a, b)
from some_nulls;
```

[image]

Asking here to get the best available solution.

Comment: There is a canonical answer: [GREATEST_IGNORE_NULLS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/greatest_ignore_nulls)

Answer (score 12):

**EDIT:**

Snowflake natively supports **[GREATEST_IGNORE_NULLS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/greatest_ignore_nulls)** and **[LEAST_IGNORE_NULLS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/least_ignore_nulls)** functions:

```
SELECT GREATEST_IGNORE_NULLS(1, 2, NULL),
       LEAST_IGNORE_NULLS(1, 2, NULL);
-- 2, 1
```

---

`GREATEST` and `LEAST` with `IGNORE NULLS` could be emulated by [ARRAY_MIN](https://docs.snowflake.com/sql-reference/functions/array_min) and [ARRAY_MAX](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_max) functions:

```
SELECT GREATEST(1,2,NULL), LEAST(1,2,NULL), 
       ARRAY_MAX([1,2,NULL]), ARRAY_MIN([1,2,NULL]);
-- NULL NULL 2 1
```

Output:

[image]

Returned output has `VARIANT` data type and it should be casted explicitly: `ARRAY_MAX([...])::NUMBER`.

| Function | Behavior equivalent |
| --- | --- |
| GREATEST(...) | GREATEST(...) RESPECT NULLS |
| LEAST(...) | LEAST(...) RESPECT NULLS |
| ARRAY_MAX(...) | GREATEST(...) IGNORE NULLS |
| ARRAY_MIN(...) | LEAST(...) IGNORE NULLS |

---

This approach works also for columns:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(col1, col2, col3) AS
SELECT 1 ,2, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 10, 20, 30;

SELECT *,
       GREATEST(col1, col2, col3),
       ARRAY_MAX([col1, col2, col3])::NUMBER
FROM tab;
```

[image]

Comment: This is really nice workaround

Comment: Yeah, this should be the accepted answer! 

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to handle nullable columns with ARRAYs:

```
SELECT a,b,c, GREATEST([a],[b],[c])[0]::INT
FROM some_nulls;
```

---

For sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE some_nulls(a INT, b INT, c INT)
AS
SELECT 1, 2, NULL UNION
SELECT NULL, 2, 3 UNION
SELECT 1, NULL, 3 UNION
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL;
```

Output:

[image]

---

How it works:

`NULL` becomes `[undefined]` which is the lowest element, therefore this approach could be used for `GREATEST` but NOT for `LEAST` function.

EDIT: As per [Denis'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4912398/denis-kokorin) comment: `-(GREATEST( [-a] ,[-b], [-c] )[0]::INT)` finds `LEAST` value

---

EDIT:
Much cleaner approach is possible with recently introduced ARRAY_MIN/MAX functions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76689938/5070879

Comment: This is fascinating, I love it. Just to show it doesn't need a cast to int, float works too: `SELECT a,b,c, GREATEST([a],[b],[c])[0]::float FROM some_nulls;`

Comment: (Side note: I see you have been fighting these monsters for many years https://stackoverflow.com/a/46267039/132438)

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Nice catch! Completely forgot about this entry :)

Comment: Since this answer is marked as correct, I will add a trick I found in other answers below:
`-(GREATEST( [-a] ,[-b], [-c] )[0]::INT` finds LEAST value - notice double negation.

Comment: @DenisKokorin  Nice idea for LEAST. Thank you.

Comment: The `LEAST` trick seems to work with INTEGER / FLOAT types but I wasn't able to apply it on TIMESTAMP type (the minus sign is not valid). any ideas how to pull the `LEAST` with TIMESTAMP columns?

Comment: @shayms8 The usage of arrays was intended as a "workaround"(hackish). It will not work for non-numeric data types.

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be to create a UDF that picks the `greatest()` or the first non null:

```sql
create or replace function greatest2(x1 float, x2 float)
returns float
as $$
    coalesce(greatest(x1, x2), x1, x2)
$$;

select greatest2(a, b)
from some_nulls;
```

[image]

However things get more complex if you need to compare multiple values. For example, if you want to compare 3 columns, then you have to create a custom UDF with 3 arguments and check each for null:

```sql
create or replace function greatest3(x1 float, x2 float, x3 float)
returns float
as $$
    select iff(x='-inf', null, x)
    from (
        select greatest(nvl(x1, '-inf'), nvl(x2, '-inf'), nvl(x3, '-inf')) x
    )
$$;

select greatest3(a, b, c)
from some_nulls;
```

[image]

Comment: This UDF only works for 2 values.  What about 3 or more?

Comment: I added one for 2 and one for 3. For more, I'd love to see more answers (or follow the same pattern as 3)

Comment: A minor issue with the second UDF is that it will return `NULL` if one of the values is legitimately `-inf`.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome user: *Felipe*

The doc's seem to describe the results exactly:

> Returns the largest value from a list of expressions. If any of the argument values is NULL, the result is NULL. GREATEST supports all data types, including VARIANT.

If you ORDER BY data, `NULL` is last, GREATEST is returning the LAST value..

Snowflake is rather consistent

```
select 
    a,b,c
    ,greatest(a, b) as g_a_b
    ,greatest(a, c) as g_a_c
    ,greatest(b, c) as g_b_c
from values
    (1.1, 2.3, null::float), 
    (null, 2, 3.5), 
    (1, null, 3), 
    (null, null, null)
    t(a,b,c)
```

gives:

| A | B | C | G_A_B | G_A_C | G_B_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1 | 2.3 | null | 2.3 | null | null |
| null | 2 | 3.5 | null | null | 3.5 |
| 1 | null | 3 | null | 3 | null |
| null | null | null | null | null | null |

so your min value `-inf` solution is interesting/gross, I mean it's correct.

But what GREATEST is doing is handling a fixed number of SQL declared columns, so the NVL soltuion works: But to make a generic solution, building the fix arrays, and then flattening, and the maxing as max handles NULL in the implicit way the problem implies which "them not being selected"

```
select a,b,c, max(f.value)
from (
    select 
        a,b,c
        ,array_construct_compact(a, b, c) as aa
    from values
        (1.1, 2.3, null), 
        (null, 2, 3.5), 
        (1, null, 3), 
        (null, null, null)
        t(a,b,c)
), table(flatten(input=>aa)) as f
group by 1,2,3,f.seq
```

gives:

| A | B | C | MAX(F.VALUE) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 3 | 3 |
| null | 2 | 3.5 | 3.5 |
| 1.1 | 2.3 | null | 2.3 |

Comment: The expectation that GREATEST skips NULL values is completely understandable: 1) `If you ORDER BY data, NULL is last, GREATEST is returning the LAST value..`  - Using this argument then [LEAST](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/least.html)  function should return the lowest value(Nulls are at the end) and it returns NULL

Comment: 2) MAX/MIN aggregate functions skip NULLs  (by analogy GREATEST/LEAST are the scalar equivalents)

3) Implementations: [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST), [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-greatest-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest#remarks) and [Databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/greatest.html) ignore NULLS.

Comment: Thanks Simeon! The problem I have with flattening arrays is that they won't run inside a SQL UDF https://stackoverflow.com/a/74527633/132438

Comment: @LukaszSzozda your "LEAST does not do the opposite" point is very valid (aka I will just believe you) where-as MAX/MIN verse GREATEST/LEAST are different "things" just like LAST_VALUE is not an aggregation function. I guess it is "rather gross" to not have a uniform handling, albeit the NULL case does feel like a floating NaN and the aggregation function have a free lunch handling, and the non-aggregation function don't.. At some level just understanding what is happening verse extension of weak implicit knowledge is needed by all.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim The GREATEST/LEAST are not defined in SQL Standard and both implementations are "correct".  The behavior of GREATEST/LEAST but also CONCAT_WS simply follows [RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-function.html#optional-parameters), I wish we had overloaded versions of these functions that skip nulls.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda yes, agreed, variants of function that allow the edge case explicitly would be best of both worlds, as both have use cases, and finding the function doesn't behave as expected "by surprise" is always a shocker.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim Now `GREATEST` and `LEAST` are part of SQL:2023 standard and the default behavior is `RESPECT NULLS`. It would be nice to have option `RESPECT/IGNORE NULLS` but I found an alternative approach to handle it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76689938/5070879

Answer (score 0):

Documenting here an approach that doesn't work (to save others time, or an opportunity to fix): Arrays in a SQL UDF.

```sql
create or replace function greatest_a(arr array)
returns float
immutable
as $$
    select max(value::float)
    from table(flatten(arr))
$$;

select greatest_a([null,2,3.3])
from some_nulls;
```

This works until you try to create the array with values from the table.

```sql
select greatest_a([a, b, c])
from some_nulls;

-- Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated
```

A similar approach with a JS UDF would work, but it will be slower than a pure SQL UDF.

Comment: Ah, I see you point, you mentioned on my answer, I dislike functions as they tend to be trying to make SQL neat and tidy very explicit about how you do the work. And the most often end up with a correlated sub-query, which are performance yuck

Answer (score 0):

Here's a yucky approach, but at least:

- It works for both `GREATEST` & `LEAST`.
- It doesn't require any synthetic values, like `-inf` (i.e. it can only return values from the fields themselves, and will never convert any valid values to `NULL`).
- It scales (uglily) to any number of parameters (it just gets harder/uglier to write with more parameters).
- The result will only be `NULL` if ***all*** the fields are NULL.

```sql
WITH test AS (
  SELECT
    column1 AS a,
    column2 AS b,
    column3 AS c,
    column4 AS d
  FROM VALUES
    ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', NULL),
    ('aaa', 'bbb', NULL, 'ccc'),
    ('aaa', NULL, 'bbb', 'ccc'),
    (NULL, 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'),
    (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
)
SELECT
  GREATEST(COALESCE(a, b, c, d), COALESCE(b, c, d, a), COALESCE(c, d, a, b), COALESCE(d, a, b, c)) AS _greatest,
  LEAST(COALESCE(a, b, c, d), COALESCE(b, c, d, a), COALESCE(c, d, a, b), COALESCE(d, a, b, c)) AS _least
FROM test;
```

We have to `COALESCE` all the values N times, each time starting with a different column (in revolving order, like a circular list), so that:

- If all the columns do have a value, all the values are compared (i.e. the first column in the `COALESCE`) to find the legitimate `GREATEST`/`LEAST`.
- If any of the columns contain `NULL`, it never surfaces (unless all of the values are `NULL`).

Result:

[image: result]

We could put the code in SQL UDFs ([which support overloading for various number of parameters](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/udf-overview.html#overloading-of-udf-names)):

- But then we'd also have to deal with specifying types, or handling automatic type conversion (unless everything is passed as `VARIANT`).
- And it can hurt performance.

I wish we didn't have to do this, even if that meant we'd have to call `GREATEST2(...)` or `LEAST2(...)`. Hopefully, Snowflake will make this a reality someday!